# Maven java: package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, discord, discord-jda

I am making a discord bot in java with JDA and I wanted to try to host it. I found out the best way to build an IntelliJ project is with maven. If I run `mvn install` i get the following error.

```
> java: package net.dv8tion.jda.api does not exist
```

I searched stack overflow and think I need to add a dependency but because this is my first time using java I really can't find out how to implement it in my project. Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem and how to implement it?

Here is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <groupId>bananaaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>DiscordBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_222</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> <!-- In Red -->
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.bananaaction.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the problem is that you didn't include JDA as a dependency (library).

In order to do this, add this to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0_222</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

See [the README of JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA#download) for details.

The first section (`<dependencies>`) declares your dependencies (libraries).

Here, you add a dependency with the group id `net.dv8tion` and artifact id `JDA` with version `4.2.0_222` (the latest version at the time of writing this (may 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2020).

The second section (`<repositories>`) defines where to look for. JDA is not in the maven central (the default) repository but in the jcenter repository so you need to add the jcenter repository to your `pom.xml`.

If you package it to a JAR, dependencies will not be included. In order to do this, you can use the `maven-assembly-plugin`, for example.

You can add the plugin to the `pom.xml` wth the following code in the `<plugins>` secion:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>yourPackage.yourClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

Integrated in your `pom.xml`, it could look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>
    <groupId>com.bananaaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>IdeaProjects</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_222</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                    <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>yourPackage.yourClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Don't forget to change the main class, however.

Comment: Hey @dan1st i really appreciate your help but i do have a question. How do i import the _maven-assembly-plugin_  in to my InteliJ project?

Comment: As I stated, add it to the `pom.xml` just like you configured the `maven-jar-plugin`.

Comment: I copied the `pom.xml` file but the name `maven-jar-plugin` is in red how do i solve that problem? Do I have to import it or am i doing something completely wrong? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You don't even need the `maven-jar-plugin`.

Comment: This is just not my day, I meant the `maven-assembly-plugin` is colored red do I have to import that or what do I have to do?

Comment: Maybe add `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>` to it.

Comment: I tried adding that but nothing has changed. I also turned on plugins because I found that while searching the web but it still is in red. I have updated the pom.xml file in my question so you can see the full code. Thanks for the help btw 

Comment: @SebastiaanTheCoder Have you try run `crtl` + `shift` + `O` to request Intellij IDEA to reload the maven module after you make the changes in your pom.xml?

Comment: @MKTan I work on a mac but I assume you mean the `Reload all maven projects` button. I have tried that a lot but it doesn't help sadly enough.